# how to get the view of the current activity? (getCurrentFocus returns null)

Tags: java, android

I want to take the screenshot of my app in code. First of all, I need to get the current view but the method **getCurrentFocus()** always returns null. What can I do?

Comment: Since you haven't provided your code, I hope that this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can only take a screenshot of what you are presenting on your view, you cannot take it of other activities or apps that are present on the screen at the time.

```
 public static Bitmap takeScreenshot(Activity activity) {  
      View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();  
      view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  
      view.buildDrawingCache();  
      Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();  
      Rect rect = new Rect();  
      activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);  
      int statusBarHeight = rect.top;  
      int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();  
      int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();  
      Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, statusBarHeight, width,  
          height - statusBarHeight);  
      view.destroyDrawingCache();  
      return bitmap2;  
    }
```

Comment: I have a question; when calling this function, how can I send the current activity as parameter?
**takeScreenshot(getActivity());**
is there something like that?

Comment: It depends on how your code is set up, but normally you are running that code from within an activity and all you have to do is: takeScreenshot(this.getActivity()) or just this

Comment: PS: please note that getActivity() is specific to phonegap Activities, you would probably be ok by just passing **this**

Comment: it says **The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}**

Comment: in that case, you cannot use this, as you are inside a new OnClickListener, at which point that will be this, so you have to do something like: **YourActivityName.this** where YourActivityName is the name of the activity in which you are setting up that view and clicklisteners